# Google webtool kit or really simple history?

Tags: ajax, gwt, google-search-console

If I want to implement [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and have the back/forward button and also a unique URL for everything fully working, should I use [Google Web Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) or really simple history?

Do they provide both these things?

It would be nice if someone with experience from these tools could share your thoughts.

EDIT: is there a difference between Google Web Toolkit and [Google Webmaster Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Webmaster_Tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Web Toolkit (GWT) is not related to Google Webmaster Tools.  GWT is a framework that compiles Java code into Javascript, and it does provide Ajax as well as the ability to handle back/forward button events.

GWT is a comprehensive framework and I've seen it work very well.  If you're willing to use a whole framework (and have enough time to learn how to use it), then I'd say give it a try, you might really like it.  However, if you were looking for a *simple* solution to add Ajax and back/forward handling to an existing site (or even a new site), I'd suggest taking a look at a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.

[Here's a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) that discusses dealing with back button functionality in jQuery.

Comment: im using jquery ajax for the ajax ability. how do i fix the url and backward/forward with jquery? could you give me some links?

Comment: Posted a link to SO thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) that discusses jQuery back button functionality.  There's plugins, or you can do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

[RSH](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/) hasn't been updated in a while, and is not particularly cross-browser compatible.

I had problems with it on www.trailbehind.com in Safari and Internet Explorer.

I meant to fix the code, but I started working on iPhone applications and haven't gotten around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit is completely different than Google Webmaster Tools.

The webmaster tools allow you to get insight on how Google ranks your pages and how the Google bot sees your content.

About the Ajax-history thing. I have tried really simple history in the past and I had lots of problems getting it to work in different browsers. I don't know if they have fixed all the problems it had in a new version.

I would recommend using [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library), Google Web Toolkit (if you really need all the Java stuff) or one of the big JavaScript libraries that are cross browser compatible ([jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), etc)